# How to pass different values of variable in SELECT statement inside plsql block

Tags: select, plsql, cursor

[image]

I am trying to solve an issue but I don't know how to solve this. Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please review [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances your chance of getting a successful answer. In particular here you need to post your procedure as text - **not an image**. Also need example data, also as text, and the expected output of that data. Finally, what have you actually tried to solve your issue; of which a better explanation other that "pass a variable" would significantly aid your case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove 'into l_deptid', cursorrec.dept_id already contains what you want.
2. Loop will not raise no_data_found, you can declare a flag variable, set it 'true' in loop block, and check in the end of procedure to raise exception if there was no rows in cursor.

Comment: You are right brother but please write the code as I'm still learning and very new to plsql.